# Angular (v2.4.5): Can't bind to 'ngTemplateOutletContext' since it isn't a known property of 'ng-container'

Tags: angular, npm, webpack

I know that there are several answered questions here with the same error but those are about migrating from Angular 4 to 5 where this property had been removed.

I'm trying to build an Angular 2.4.5 project with webpack. After a few modifications and npms it build without an error but when I try to run I get the following error in the browser console:

> Template parse errors: Can't bind to 'ngTemplateOutletContext' since
>   it isn't a known property of 'ng-container'.

I don't use any `ngTemplateOutletContext` properties, so I don't know where this is coming from. I suppose that I have updated some package by mistake and others stayed old, so the updated package throws the error. The project was built about 2 years ago using the dotnet core aspnetcore spa angular template.

How can I detect the root of this error? What can cause this error in an angular 2.4.5 project?

package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^2.4.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "^2.4.5",
    "@angular/core": "^2.4.5",
    "@angular/forms": "^2.4.5",
    "@angular/http": "^2.4.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^2.4.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^2.4.5",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^2.4.5",
    "@angular/router": "^3.4.5",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.42",
    "angular2-modal": "^2.0.3",
    "angular2-platform-node": "~2.0.11",
    "angular2-template-loader": "^0.6.2",
    "aspnet-prerendering": "^2.0.0",
    "aspnet-webpack": "^1.0.17",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "crypto": "^1.0.1",
    "css": "^2.2.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.25.0",
    "es6-promise": "^4.2.5",
    "es6-shim": "^0.35.1",
    "event-source-polyfill": "^0.0.7",
    "expose-loader": "^0.7.1",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.0-rc",
    "file-loader": "^0.9.0",
    "html-loader": "^0.4.4",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "^2.2.1",
    "jquery": "^2.2.4",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.4",
    "ng-select": "^1.0.0-beta.5",
    "preboot": "^4.5.2",
    "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "rxjs": "^5.4.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "to-string-loader": "^1.1.5",
    "typescript": "^2.3.4",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.7",
    "webpack": "^2.2.0",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.12.2",
    "webpack-merge": "^0.14.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.8"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/chai": "^3.4.34",
    "@types/core-js": "^2.5.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.5.37",
    "@types/jquery": "^2.0.41",
    "chai": "^3.5.0",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.5.2",
    "karma": "^1.3.0",
    "karma-chai": "^0.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-webpack": "^1.8.0"
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I detect the root of this error?

You have to remove everything and slowly add back piece by piece until you hit just the *things* causing the error.

Strip down your `AppModule` to the minimum and update your *bootstrap* component so that it does nothing. Comment out all the HTML in the template and comment out all of the logic of the component.

You want your `AppModule` to import *nothing* important. Just the basic browser module and common module.

Slowly, start adding back the pieces of the bootstrap component. Try to leave the *router* for last and any third-party modules.

If you *hit* the issue again when adding the *router* or a *module*. Try to comment out all of the route configuration and until you get it runnable again.

Keep repeating this process until you narrow down to where the issue is. You'll find it when you reproduce it with the least amount of dependencies.